# Background Worker, C# - Objects sharing between workers - Creating issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm facing an serious issue where data from one record is copied to another record (Overlay).  I'm using MQ request for communicating to Mainframe systems using my C# code. we are facing issue which is very random/rarer where sending update request to Mainframe for one record copy information of another record previously processed by that thread. I'm using below code Background worker approach to create multi-threading on my servers.

My Question here is : Can objects created by one worker being used by another work ? is that possible ? this may be one of reason of overlay data.

Please help with you suggestion !!

```
        BackgroundWorker worker;
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
        worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Your current code does not show objects you are referring?

Comment: (2) whether the two workers/threads are calling methods on that object concurrently or not.  I'm suspecting this - Because we process Millions of records each day. But we get this issue only one's or twice a week for 2-3 Records only - How I can check how many workers are created by background process and how I can restrict workers using same object (in that case as well when calling concurrently) . Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    struct SOmeData { }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        SOmeData data = new SOmeData();

        // backgroundWorker1 result
        e.Result = data;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // backgroundWorker1 result
        SOmeData data = (SOmeData)e.Result;

        // start backgroundWorker2
        backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync(data);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // backgroundWorker1 result
        SOmeData data = (SOmeData)e.Argument;
    }
}
```